# Get key in multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create array with carriers names and ids binded to them. And then I want execute some like `get_carrier_name_by_id(id)` what will return carrier name.

```
$carriers = array (
    "DPD" => array(1,2,3),
    "DPD Pobranie" => array(4,5,6),
    "Poczta-Polska" => array(7,8,9),
    "Poczta-Polska pobranie" => array(10,11,12),
    "Paczkomat" => array(13,14,15),
    "Paczkomat pobranie" => array(16,17,18),
    "Osobisty" => array(19,20,21),
    "UPS" => array(22,23,24),
    "UPS pobranie" => array(25,26,27)
);
```

Is this properly way to keep data?

Comment: What you're describing is also referred to as a map or associative array or dictionary and is a legitimate way of storing data. It's also a core data structure in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function get_carrier_name_by_id($id)
{
    $carriers = array (
        "DPD" => array(1,2,3),
        "DPD Pobranie" => array(4,5,6),
        "Poczta-Polska" => array(7,8,9),
        "Poczta-Polska pobranie" => array(10,11,12),
        "Paczkomat" => array(13,14,15),
        "Paczkomat pobranie" => array(16,17,18),
        "Osobisty" => array(19,20,21),
        "UPS" => array(22,23,24),
        "UPS pobranie" => array(25,26,27)
    );

    foreach($carriers as $name => $ids)
        if(in_array($id, $ids))
            return $name;

    return null;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(get_carrier_name_by_id(122));
var_dump(get_carrier_name_by_id(12));
```

Outputs of `var_dump`s:

```
NULL
string(22) "Poczta-Polska pobranie"
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [array iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php).

look below solution using iterator:

```
function get_carrier_name_by_id($id)
{
    $carriers = array(
        "DPD" => array(1, 2, 3),
        "DPD Pobranie" => array(4, 5, 6),
        "Poczta-Polska" => array(7, 8, 9),
        "Poczta-Polska pobranie" => array(10, 11, 12),
        "Paczkomat" => array(13, 14, 15),
        "Paczkomat pobranie" => array(16, 17, 18),
        "Osobisty" => array(19, 20, 21),
        "UPS" => array(22, 23, 24),
        "UPS pobranie" => array(25, 26, 27)
    );

    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($carriers));

    foreach ($it as $key => $val) {
        $key = $it->getSubIterator($it->getDepth() - 1)->key();
        if($val == $id){
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

echo get_carrier_name_by_id(3); //Output: DPD
echo get_carrier_name_by_id(12); //Output: Poczta-Polska pobranie
echo get_carrier_name_by_id(24); //Output: UPS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily obtain Carrier Name using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
$key = 4;
$carrier = key( array_filter( $carriers, function( $row ) use( $key ) { return in_array( $key, $row ); } ) );
echo $carrier;
```

will output:

```
DPD Pobranie
```

Basically, you have to filter `$carriers` array to matched `$key`. You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php): `array_filter` pass each array element to the called function and if the function returns a value evaluable as True, the element is returned in the filtered array, otherwise it is discarded. In your case, we check if in element items there is the requested key.

Then, we use [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) to return the key of currently pointed element of filtered array: the array is just created, so the pointer is at the start of array.

You can adapt this script to a function, if you want:

```
function CarrierByID( $carriers, $key )
{
    return key( ... );
}
```